# ADO.NET/C# reading CSV into a DataTable fails when the file name contains special characters

Tags: c#, csv, ado.net

I use the code below to load a CSV file into an ADO.NET DataTable. command.Fill fails when the CSV filename contains certain special characters. I was savvy enough to place square brackets around the filename in the command-text:

```
"SELECT * FROM [{0}]"
```

I assumed the square brackets were protection against special characters causing said error. An example of a CSV filename that causes it to fail is AdventureWorks.Person.Person.csv.

```
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCSV(string folderPath, string csvFileName)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string connectionText = String.Format(
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='{0}';Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes';",
        folderPath);
    string commandText = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", csvFileName);

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionText))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (OleDbDataAdapter command = new OleDbDataAdapter(commandText, connection))
        {
            command.Fill(table);
            command.Dispose();
        }

        connection.Close();
    }

    return table;
}
```

Comment: I can see why it does not work. It will try treat it like schemaname.dboname.tablename format

Comment: Update: I created a table with multiple dots and had select query for it and it worked. Can you add error details.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it is a CSV file on disk not a table. I used AdventureWorks to make the CSV and saved it as AdventureWorks.Person.Person.csv. In no ways is it access SQL Server. That is the Jet 4.0 provider access a specific CSV file within a folder.